# Difference between show and print_ data function

Tags: haskell

Can anyone tell me what the difference between the print_data function below and the built in show function in Haskell?

```
let print_data v =
    case v of
        I a -> show a
        F v -> show v
        S v -> v
```

Comment: Yes, many people can... but why do you ask? What is confusing to you? Have you just tried to run it?

Comment: Hint: Look at its type and compare it to `show`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in function will show a value like `I 3` as the string `I 3`. Yours will only show `3`.

Similarly, the built-in on `S "abc"` will produce the string `S "abc"`. Yours will only produce `abc`.

(And similarly for `F`.)

You can confirm this by trying it on a few cases in GHCi.